# Website Detect "In-House Access"

Tags: web, local

TL;DR: How to detect local website users?

I have a self-hosted website running in the student-building I live in. In this website I would like a page for and links to certain local applications, like the webremote of the RPi running Kodi, an FTP, a page of instructions etc.

I don't want those to be visible to random internet users, so is there any way for a website to detect whether the user is accessing the website from inside the local network? Preferably in JavaScript, but PHP would also be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in PHP it can be done in several ways.  The simplest way is to do a simple IP check.

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = "10.1.0.25") {  // Internet IP or IP rangehere
   // Show links for internal users
} else {
   // Show stuff for all other users
}
```

or for range of IPs assuming 192.168.1.x addresses

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] >= "192.168.1.1" && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] <= "192.168.1.1") {
  // Internal Info
} else {
  // External Info
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. `REMOTE_ADDR` is 192.168.x.x when accessing the server through the internal server IP and it returns the WAN IP of the router if accessed through the DNS name. Follow-up question: is there a way to find the server WAN address, so I can compare it to `REMOTE_ADDR`? I tried `SERVER_ADDR`, but it only gives the internal server IP.

Comment: I'm not aware of a PHP function that will readily provide that information.  I stand to be corrected though ...